# Initial screen is badly displayed on startup

Tags: flutter

With this 1.2.1 version I get a strange first screen on my iPhone

[image] (cf. attached image).
Any idea ?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: Isn't that related to the beta version? Did you try to downgrade your version?

Comment: We need more info. Does it happen on Android as well? Does it happen on the emulator? Different devices?

Comment: I have "only" tested on different real iPhone. Not tested on Android yet and not tested on emulator. I will try to downgrade during the day

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (only on iOS) on production app... After hours of trying to find the solution, experimenting with Widgets combinations, devices etc. appeared, that the problem is the **Flutter version**. 
In fact, I have no idea why is that happening and where the problem is, but downgrading Flutter (Channel beta) to version **1.1.8** solved the problem.

My current Flutter version:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.1.8, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G4015, locale pl-PL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```